# Getting data between given date range by comparing two dates in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table **trans** and it has columns like tranno, start_date, stop_date. Data is as follows.

```
tranno, start_date, stop_date
123, 07-jul-2019, 06-jun-2020
124, 07-jul-2020, 06-jun-2021
125, 07-jul-2021, 06-jun-2022
126, 07-jul-2022, 06-jun-2023
```

My requirement is , I want to get trans between given date range. Lets say i want trans between 08-jul-2020 and 10-aug-2022. Then my output should be like

```
Tranno
124
125
126
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `start_date` and `stop_date` columns are bona fide date columns, then you may use the overlapping date range formula here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE stop_date  >= '2020-07-08'::date AND
      start_date <= '2022-08-10'::date;
```

If you are literally storing *text* dates as e.g. `07-jul-2019`, then the best thing to do would be to change your table design and store proper dates.